# isomorphic $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ with nonisomorphic $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graded-rings, projective-schemes

Let $S$ be a graded ring. To understand $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ better, I want to know under what changes of $S$ will $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ remains unchanged. All answers from a proposition or general point of view are welcome. I will start with some examples: Fix an integer $k$.

1. scaling:  define a new graded ring with $S'_d = S_{dk}$. Then $\operatorname{Proj}(S)\cong \operatorname{Proj}(S')$
2. replace a finite number of terms by $0$ and remain the grading. $S'_{n} = 0$ for $0\leq  n \leq k$ and $S'_{n} = S_{n}$ for $n \geq k+1.$

Comment: It should be noted that if you require your rings to have $1$ (this is very common) then you can't set $S_0=0$ in your second bit. There's a third thing you can do: you can change $S_0$ to some other ring $A$ with a homomorphism to $S_0$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329678/quasi-coherent-sheaf-on-proj-s/3337698#3337698) for details. It's tempting to say that this is all you can do, but a proof of that seems rather difficult because proj is not so well-behaved - it's not a functor, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the materials!